# Ito's lemma applied to functions involving stopping times

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, stopping-times

Recently, I come across an exercise in my book that asks us to apply Ito's formula to
$$Y_t = e^{rt} \mathbf{1}_{ \{ \tau \leq t \} },$$ where $\tau$ is a stopping time. However, this is an inherent issue about computing $d \mathbf{1}_{ \{ \tau \leq t \} }$, as paths are non-differentiable. Can anyone explain to me the expression for $dY_t$?

Comment: But this process has finite variation, why should you need Itô's formula?. You can just say $dY_t = rY_t$ if $\tau <t$ and 0 otherwise right?